# Android samsung galaxy S3 imageview not displaying correctly

Tags: android, imageview, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I am developing an application that uses big images (more than 2000px height). I made images for the different density scaling and the tests on all emulators and physical phones are giving good results. All, except on the Samsung Galaxy S3 physical phone. It refuses to render correctly the image of more than 2000px height. (It draws a totally shrinked version of the image). Running my app on an emulator for the S3 gives fine results. Making the image less than 2000px height shows the image correctly as well. What can be the cause of this strange behaviour?

I am using the following layout for my image view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
      <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
 
            **<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:scaleType="center" />**
           </LinearLayout>                            
        </ScrollView>
   </LinearLayout>
```

The emulator on which the images are working fine has the following details:

```
 Target: Google APIs (Google Inc) - API Level 15
 SD Card: size: 1024mb
 Skin:Built In: WXGA720
 Hardware:
        Abstracted LCD Density: 320
        VM application heap size: 48
        Device ram size: 1024
```

Comment: I have the same problem. ImageView shrinks on galaxy note